# Interpret hazard ratio that has huge value

Tags: survival, proportional-hazards

I run a coxph model in R using survival package. Here's the output

```
> coxph = coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma, data = first.data, method = "breslow")
> summary(coxph)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma, data = first.data, 
    method = "breslow")

  n= 49, number of events= 46 
   (1 observation deleted due to missingness)

           coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
tr.ma     9.520 13633.375     3.906 2.437   0.0148 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

      exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
tr.ma     13633  7.335e-05      6.45  28817913

Concordance= 0.694  (se = 0.058 )
Rsquare= 0.109   (max possible= 0.997 )
Likelihood ratio test= 5.68  on 1 df,   p=0.01718
Wald test            = 5.94  on 1 df,   p=0.0148
Score (logrank) test = 5.93  on 1 df,   p=0.01485
```

I know `exp(coef) = 13633.375`means that at any given time, an individual with `tr.ma = x` is 13633.375 times more likely to die than does an individual with `tr.ma = x-1` at that same time. However that ratio seems huge to me. `tr.ma` is a proportion, so its value is between -1 and 1. If I run summary on `tr.ma` I get

```
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
-0.05098  0.03049  0.04587  0.05164  0.07519  0.17260        1
```

Can that magnitude of the hazard ratio be compatible with the magnitude of the covariate `tr.ma`?

EDIT: So I multiplied `tr.ma` by 100 to get "percentages" (some of which are negative) and rerun the model. Here's the output:

```
> summary(first.data$tr.ma)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 -5.098   3.049   4.587   5.164   7.519  17.260       1 

> coxph = coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma, data = first.data, method = "breslow")
> summary(coxph)
 Call:
 coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma, data = first.data, 
     method = "breslow")

   n= 49, number of events= 46 
    (1 observation deleted due to missingness)

          coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
 tr.ma 0.09520   1.09988  0.03906 2.437   0.0148 *
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

       exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
 tr.ma       1.1     0.9092     1.019     1.187

 Concordance= 0.694  (se = 0.058 )
 Rsquare= 0.109   (max possible= 0.997 )
 Likelihood ratio test= 5.68  on 1 df,   p=0.01718
 Wald test            = 5.94  on 1 df,   p=0.0148
 Score (logrank) test = 5.93  on 1 df,   p=0.01485
```

The hazard ratio is now 1.09988. Note that the p-value in both cases are the same. Can anyone explain how transforming the scale of the covariate changes the scale of the hazard ratio (if that's the right question to ask from observing the difference between the two scales of `tr.ma`).

#### Proportionality assumption test

```
> test = cox.zph(coxph)
> test
> plot(test)
        rho chisq      p
 tr.ma -0.34  5.49 0.0192
```

[image: beta for tr.ma over time]

Is the curvature too much to say that the proportionality assumption is met? If it is not, what can I do?

Comment: The independent variable has such a small range that it perhaps exaggerated the HR. Consider instead of using HR for 1 unit change, come up with a more reasonable change such as 1 SD change in tr.ma or one inter-quartile range change, etc. Form 1st quartile to 3rd quartile is only 0.045... exp(9.52*0.045) is only 1.53, a lot more reasonable than reporting 13633.

Comment: Could you please say a bit more about the nature of the "proportion" that `tr.ma` represents? Your results might be more easily interpreted if the regression were done in terms of the 2 underlying variables that together give the `tr.ma` values, rather than just that proportion alone. Also, have you checked whether the proportional hazards assumption seems OK with respect to this `tr.ma` variable?

Comment: @EdM Thank you for the suggestion. I added the proportionality test and plot. It looks like the proportionality assumption is not met. What would you suggest to do?

Comment: @EdM ```tr.ma``` is a lagging moving average of the proportional change in the value of interest over time. For example, ```tr = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7]``` then ```tr.change = [NA, 1, 2, -1, 4] , tr.ma = [NA, NA, NA, 2/3, 5/3]```.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. It seems that `tr.ma` is thus a time-dependent covariate, but your `Surv()` object doesn't seem structured to handle a time-dependent covariate; it only has one `time` variable, not the 2 expected in the `Surv(start,stop,event)` syntax for time dependence. Please clarify.

Comment: Also, the way I understand the example of `tr.ma` in your comment, it seems to be a 3-item moving average of `tr.change`, not of a _proportional_ change.

Comment: @EdM thank you for pointing that out. ```tr.ma``` is indeed time-dependent. ```time``` in the model specification is the time-until-event, i.e. stop - start, so I didn't think it was necessary to include start and stop. Is that correct?

Comment: @EdM you're right the example I gave isn't proportional change. In particular ```tr.change``` should be ```[NA, 1/1, 2/2, -1/4, 4/3]```.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the main question, the interpretation of extremely high hazard ratios (HRs). As implicit in the comment from @Penguin_Knight, this is simply an issue of scales like, for example, in expressions of speed. A vehicle that is traveling at 100 km/hour has the same speed as one traveling at 100,000,000 millimeter/hour. An HR value is expressed as relative hazard per unit change in the predictor variable. If you, as in your example, change from fractional to percentage units then you will lower the numerical value of the HR by a factor of 100. Same actual relative hazard in any real sense, just different units.

In your case, the problem is exacerbated by your choice of predictor variable. The `tr.ma` variable is an (averaged) fractional (or percentage) rate of change of some variable of interest, which we shall call $X$. Let's start with the simple case where there is a single value of `tr.ma` associated with each case at the time of entry into the study, a value which does not change with time. I see two issues here.

First, how is one supposed to understand the interpretation of the associated hazard ratio: the change in hazard per percentage change of the rate of change of $X$? That requires a good deal of explanation. Can be done, but it's rather complicated; you're asking the reader to evaluate something like an acceleration.

Second, the use of a ratio or percentage as a predictor variable poses difficulties. What happens, for example, if the value of $X$ is small, close to 0? Furthermore, you are throwing out information about the actual value of $X$.

In regression, whether Cox or otherwise, for these and other reasons you will typically be better off including the actual values of the variables that go into the ratio, rather than using their ratio as a single predictor. If $X$ is necessarily positive in value, you could include the log of its present value and the log of some past value as predictors; if the rate of change of $X$ with time is truly a useful predictor, then the signs of the coefficients of these log-transformed values should be of opposite sign and approximately equal magnitude. If there is a more complicated (or interesting) relation of $X$ to survival, then you may find it by including both contributors to your percentage change of $X$ but you would miss it if you restricted yourself to the percentage change as the only predictor. With 46 events you should be able to handle 2 predictors without overfitting.

Finally, there is the issue of whether `tm.ma` (or some other functions of $X$, as recommended) is a time-dependent predictor. If this value can change between the start time and the event/censoring time for an individual, and you think that the current value (rather than simply its value at the start time) is related to the hazard of having an event, then you need to set this up as an analysis with time-dependent covariates. The `survival` package in R has a vignette explaining how to handle time-dependent covariates. I can't say whether these suggestions will solve your problem with non-proportional hazards, but they may well help.